# I have created an array, which needs to be randomised when I click a button and show one of the arrays. I have used PHP and HTML for this

Tags: php, html, arrays, submit

I am new to PHP/HTML and I want a random card from a pack of cards to be shown when I click a button.

I have this code so far, however I really don't know what I have done wrong. Would I be able to get some help? Thanks.

```
<form action="cards.php" method="get">
<input type=submit value="submit" name=draw>
</form>
<?php
$s=$_GET["draw"];
if ($s=="true")
{

    $cards[0]="1C";
    $cards[1]="2C";
    $cards[2]="3C";
    $cards[3]="4C";
    $cards[4]="5C";
    $cards[5]="6C";
    $cards[6]="7C";
    $cards[7]="8C";
    $cards[8]="9C";
    $cards[9]="10C";
    $cards[10]="AC";
    $cards[11]="KC";
    $cards[12]="QC";
    $cards[13]="JC";
    $cards[14]="1D";
    $cards[15]="2D";
    $cards[16]="3D";
    $cards[17]="4D";
    $cards[18]="5D";
    $cards[19]="6D";
    $cards[20]="7D";
    $cards[21]="8D";
    $cards[22]="9D";
    $cards[23]="10D";
    $cards[24]="AD";
    $cards[25]="KD";
    $cards[26]="QD";
    $cards[27]="JD";
    $cards[28]="1H";
    $cards[28]="2H";
    $cards[29]="3H";
    $cards[30]="4H";
    $cards[31]="5H";
    $cards[32]="6H";
    $cards[33]="7H";
    $cards[34]="8H";
    $cards[35]="9H";
    $cards[36]="10H";
    $cards[37]="AH";
    $cards[38]="KH";
    $cards[39]="QH";
    $cards[40]="JH";
    $cards[41]="1S";
    $cards[42]="2S";
    $cards[43]="3S";
    $cards[44]="4S";
    $cards[45]="5S";
    $cards[46]="6S";
    $cards[47]="7S";
    $cards[48]="8S";
    $cards[49]="9S";
    $cards[50]="10S";
    $cards[51]="AS";
    $cards[52]="KS";
    $cards[53]="QS";
    $cards[54]="JS";

    srand($cards);

    echo (rand (0-54));

}
?>
```

Comment: Select all your code and hit the `{}` button in the toolbar. Don't wrap each individual line in backticks!

Comment: $_GET["draw"] would be undefined since it is not initialized.

Comment: Also - your card array is incorrect; you have a 1 of each suit, as well as an Ace, and `$cards[28]` is declared twice. For something like that, it's much easier to populate the array using loops.

Comment: It'll be more common to declare your array like `$cards = array('1C','2C', '3C', etc.);`

Comment: Also your statements `$s=$_GET["draw"]; if ($s=="true")` are wrong, `$s` will never be `"true"` because the value of `$_GET["draw"]` is "submit" (according to your <input>). So you should use `if (isset($_GET['draw']))` or `if(!empty($_GET['draw']))` or `if(isset($_GET['draw']) && $_GET['draw'] == 'submit')` or `if(!emply($_GET['draw']) && $_GET['draw'] == 'submit')` or even `if(isset($_GET['draw']) && $_GET['draw'] == true)` (`true` without quotation marks so it'll be a boolean type, not a string, but anyway I'll not recommend to use boolean comparison in that case).

Answer (score 1):

in your php, just do

```
shuffle($cards);
echo $cards[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll should use the `array_rand` function:

```
$values = array_rand($input, 1);
```

Note:

You can create an array much quicker and cleaner like this:

```
$array = array(
     "a",
     "b",
     "c",
     "d",
);
```